# C# / .NET Keep named pipe open and support any number of parallel connecting clients

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

We have multiple clients connect to the server over named pipes. Occasionally we are seeing a `pipe/file not found` error when the client tries to connect to a named pipe. Our original code is

```
    while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // This creates a new NamedPipeServerStream
        var stream = PipeHelper.NewCurrentUserServerStream(PipeNames.Server, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
        await stream.WaitForConnectionAsync(cancelToken);

        Task.Run(() => HandleStreamAsync(stream).WithExceptionTrapper(LogNamedPipeException));
```

From what I can tell, a `NamedPipeServerStream` should be created and then `WaitForConnection` should be called, then the server should handle the request.

However, if that request is near instantaneous, or the client shuts down the pipe, it seems possible that the server stream will be closed and the whole named pipe will disappear, before the code loops around and a new server stream is created.

**So how do we ensure the named pipe exists for the lifetime of the server, regardless of timing and number of connecting clients?**

The code here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication suggests that simply using a number of threads is an option (4, in that example). However this seems to only reduce the probability of error and its possible to have a client try to connect in a rare gap where all 4 threads have just closed a server stream and the named pipe disappears. In addition, it limits the parallel execution to 4 threads.

Is there a mechanism to allow us to open a named pipe server which allows arbitrary numbers of connections, creates a new server stream for every connection and never risks closing the named pipe?

Right now we are thinking about doing this:

```
    var nextStream = PipeHelper.NewCurrentUserServerStream(PipeNames.Server, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
    while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            await nextStream.WaitForConnectionAsync(cancelToken);
            var currentStream = nextStream;
            // Always have another stream ready so if the task is handled and finished 
            // really quickly theres no chance of the named pipe being removed altogether.
            nextStream = PipeHelper.NewCurrentUserServerStream(PipeNames.Server, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);

            Task.Run(() => HandleStreamAsync(currentStream).WithExceptionTrapper(LogNamedPipeException));
        }
```

This basically ensures we create a 2nd server stream before we start handling the 1st server stream connection, so we're guaranteed there is always one active, and we're running the handler on a separate task so we should start another WaitForConnection as soon as possible.

**Is there a framework pattern that allows us to do the above, supporting any number of parallel clients and ensuring the named pipe is never removed provided the server is still active?**

Answer (score 1):

> So how do we ensure the named pipe always exists regardless of timing and number of connecting clients?

This isn't possible for any kind of network server. Even TCP/IP (on which named pipes are built) has a limited "backlog". Even if you modify the backlog to be a ridiculous amount, you'll still be limited by server hardware.

What you *can* do is always keep a certain number of listening calls (i.e., `WaitForConnectionAsync`), so you always have a good number of listeners going at all times, starting a new listen as soon as each one completes, just like your last code example. You'll want to run that code several times, like 20 or so, so you have lots of listeners. All you can do is minimize the chance of missing a connection; you can't prevent it completely.

Comment: The code we have suggests we don't even need a listening call to prevent the client failing on 'pipe/file not found', we just need a stream created that ensures the pipe is there, regardless of if there are active listeners. So we can create and hold (and never use) a server stream for as long as the process is active. However I'm wondering if the client model we have is wrong here. Is it correct to assume that it's always the server creating the pipe, and the client relies on the pipe existing? Or is the client typically capable of creating the pipe if it gets there first?

Comment: @MichaelParker: It's been almost two decades since I've dealt with named pipes, but I believe that the server side has to be created first. There's patterns where the server and client can be created simultaneously, but not in different processes IIRC.

Comment: Ok, thats good in a way (we didn't overlook something). I found a similar problem in the microsoft Go code: https://github.com/Microsoft/go-winio/pull/80/commits/ecd994be061f4ae21f463bbf08166d8edc96cadb where they are trying to deal with the same race condition. Their solution is to start a server stream and immediately a client stream (on the server side) to hold the pipe open but prevent clients from connecting to the first server stream. Then open new server streams to deal with the real clients. It seems crazy but I can port this to C# unless theres a better solution?